# Spivak, Ch. 3 Functions, Problem 7a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem asks us to prove that for any polynomial function $f$ and any (real) number $a$, there is a polynomial function $g$ and a (real) number $b$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x) + b$ for all $x$. It notes that a formal proof is possible via induction on the degree of $f$.

The solution manual has a very weird solution that doesn't even seem correct (but I may be wrong about that).

**I will write my solution below, and I'd like to know if the proof is correct. After my solution I will copy the solution manual solution.**

I will use induction on the degree of $f$.

Let $A=\{n:f_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ can be written as $(x-a)g(x)+b\}$

$n=1\implies f_1(x)=a_1 x +a_0$

We can either do long division by $x-a$ or we can equate $f_1$ to $g(x)(x-a)+b$ to find that

$$f_1=(x-a)a_1+(a_0+a a_1)$$
$$g(x)=a_1$$
$$b = a_0+a a_1$$
$$\implies 1 \in A$$

Assume $k \in A$.
This means $f_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i x^i=(x-a)g(x)+b$

$$f_{k+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k+1}a_i x^i = f_k(x)+a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$$

The term $a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$ equals $x a_{k+1}x^k$ and $a_{k+1}x^k$ is a $k^{th}$ degree polynomial so we can write

$$a_{k+1} x^{k+1}=x a_{k+1} x^k=x((x-a)l(x)+b_1)$$
where I used $a_{k+1}x^k=(x-a)l(x)+b_1$ for some polynomial $l(x)$ of degree k, and a real number $b_1$.

$$f_{k+1}=(x-a)(g(x)+l(x)x)+b+b_1x$$

But $b+b_1x$ is a first degree polynomial so we can write

$$b+b_1x=(x-a)b_1+b+ab_1$$

$$\implies f_{k+1}=(x-a)(g(x)+l(x)x+b_1)+b+ab_1$$

We can call $g(x)+l(x)x+b_1$ a function $g_{k+1}$ and $b+ab_1$ we can call $b_{k+1}$

$$\implies f_{k+1}=(x-a)g_{k+1}(x)+b_{k+1}$$

$$\implies k+1 \in A$$

$$\implies A = \mathbb{N}$$

Ie, we've proved that the statement of the problem is true for functions $f(x)$ of any degree $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**I'm going to post here the solution from the solution manual as it is written there:**

If the degree of $f$ is 1, then f is of the form
$$f(x) = cx + d=c(x-a)+(d+ac)$$
so $g(x)=c$ and $b=d+ac$.

Suppose the result is true for polynomials of degree $\leq k$. If $f$ has degree $k+1$, then $f$ has the form $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_i x^i$.

Now the polynomial function $h(x) = f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-a)$ has degree $\leq k$, so we can write

$$f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-1)=(x-a)g(x)+b$$
**The next step I don't understand. I am writing it exactly as it appears in the solutions manual**
$$f(x) = (x-a)(g(x)+a_{k+1})+b$$
"which is the required form".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some errors in the solution manual as $h(x)=f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-a)$ does not need to have smaller degree. I believe it should be

$$\begin{align}h(x)= f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}\end{align}.$$ The highest order term in $(x-a)^{k+1}$ is $x^{k+1}$ and so the first term cancels with the first term in $f$ meaning $h$ has smaller degree (whatever the next highest degree in $f$ was).

Then you get $h(x)= (x-a)g(x)+b$ by induction and rearrange to see

$$f(x) = (x-a)(g(x)+a_{k+1}(x-a)^k)+b.$$

Your proof seems correct, but requires a few extra steps. This is because when you subtract $a_{k+1}x^{k+1}$ you have changed the value of the polynomial at $x=a$ and so the value of $b$ must change. But by subtracting $a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}$ which is $0$ at $x=a$ you do not change the value of the polynomial at $x=a$.

Comment: Indeed I see the error of the solution manual now. Regarding my proof, where are you saying I subtracted $a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$? I assumed $h(x)=f(x)+a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$, I then manipulated the last term such that it has a $k^{th}$ degree polynomial factor times $x$, used the induction assumption on the $k^{th}$ degree term, subbed this in the original $h(x)$ equation, and then saw a first degree polynomial and used the induction assumption again. I can't see where I made a subtraction.

Comment: In your proof $f_{k+1}$ is playing the role of $f$. $f_k$ plays the role of $h$. So you wrote $f= h+a_{k+1}x^{k+1}$. Which if you solve for $h$ is $h=f-a_{k+1}x^{k+1}$. It's true you didnt write it as subtraction.